# Cypress - How do I check that a value is only to 1 decimal place?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, cypress

I'm trying to find a way of validating that a value pulled out is ALWAYS displayed to one decimal place.

Let's say for argument sake:

Length = 15.6

I'm currently invoking the value as LengthValue.
How do I check that LengthValue is equal to 1DP?
This is for a bug that's been identified where the Length value was displayed as 15.6000000

```
      cy.get('Length')
          .invoke('val') 
        .as('LengthValue')
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to split the string provided by `invoke()` by the decimal point and count the RHS.

```js
cy.get('Length').invoke('val')
  .then(strvalue => {
    return strvalue.split('.')[1].length
  })
  .should('eq', 1)  // length RHS is one
```

I'm not sure what you intend with the alias, but you can add that above if it's useful later in the test.